# offline data storage & access using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-gears, offline-mode

does anybody have any experience writing up a offline data storage & access app on jquery. my server side app would be an ASP.Net app. basically, i would be providing a trimmed down version of my web app so that users could access some of the data while they are offline and can sync the data when they connect again. I have heard of google gears but wanted to hear from people who have used it or who know more on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to impossible to do without a plugin since your only option is a Cookie which has a 4k limit.

Looks like the jquery-store that others have suggested uses Flash as a data store.
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jstore/ . I am biased and don't like flash unless absolutely necessary. I have had issues with it and memory. So here are some other options:

Google Gears seems to be the one that is going to be what you want.
http://gears.google.com/

Gears it is not jQuery specific. Someone is writing a jQuery wrapper for it http://code.google.com/p/jquery-offline/

Answer (score 1):

this can be of some help [jquery-offline](https://github.com/wycats/jquery-offline#readme)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few jquery plugins for that:
http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/1589

Also this a good post about the matter: